# An Application of Farkas' Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

The Farkas' lemma I know is:

> Exactly one of the following systems has a solution. 
>   \begin{equation} 
> \left\{ 
>     \begin{array}{l}
>      Ax=b,\ x\geq0 \\
>      A^Ty\geq0, \ y^Tb<0
>     \end{array} \right.  
> \end{equation}

I want to find the alternative system for
\begin{equation}
c^Tx<0,Ax\geq0,Bx=0
\end{equation}

My solution is:

\begin{equation}
\left(
    \begin{array}{c}
    A\\
    B\\
    -B
    \end{array}
\right)x\geq0, x^Tc<0
\end{equation}
By Farkas' Lemma, we have the corresponding alternative system
\begin{equation}
(A^T\ B^T\ -B^T)
\left(
    \begin{array}{c}
    y_1\\
    y_2\\
    y_3
    \end{array}
\right)=c,\quad y_1,y_2,y_3\geq0
\end{equation}

Can anyone tell me whether my solution is correct? I'm not sure about $y_2$ and $y_3$, it seems there's some relation between $y_2$ and $y_3$ through $B^T$... Should I "rewrite" $y_2$ and $y_3$ into a vector $v$ such that $v=y_2-y_3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Your equation is $A^T y_1 + B^T y_2 - B^T y_3 = c$, which is equivalent to to $A^T y_1 + B^T( y_2 - y_3) = c$. You can indeed replace $y_2-y_3$ with $v$. What can you say about the sign of $v$?

Comment: I can not tell the sign of $v$... So it is correct to just left $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$ over there? It is confused to me that at the beginning we have only $x$ but end up with three $y$s.

Comment: what do you mean that you cannot tell the sign of $v$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean I don't know the sign of $v$.

Comment: that's right, so you get $A^Ty_1 + B^T v = c$, with $y_1 \geq 0$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: Got it, thanks for your replying and patience!